# Another question concerning finite metacyclic groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Given a non-split finite metacyclic group $H$, does there always exist a finite split metacyclic group $G$ with a normal cyclic subgroup $N$ of prime power order such that $H \cong G/N$?

Based on my computations, this appears to be true at least for non-split metacyclic groups of orders up to 500, and also for some specific classes of metacyclic groups such as dicyclic groups, $Q_{2^n} \times \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ ($p$ prime), etc.

Comment: What do you mean with "with a cyclic $p$-group"? $p$ is not quantified, and "with" is ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity in the question. I hope that the new (rewritten) version is well-posed.

Comment: If $G,H$ are non-split metacyclic groups of $p$-power, resp. $q$-power order, for distinct primes $p,q$, what do you think of $G\times H$?